# Can multiple Android IntentServices run at the same time?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-intentservice

From what I understand, an `IntentService` can only handle one Intent at a time as it shares a worker thread to do all of its work. But if I have multiple `IntentService`s in my app, can they run in parallel, or do they all share the single worker thread as well?

Comment: Never tried it before, why not just try it?

Comment: I'm lazy. I just tried it and they do indeed run in parallel. I'll accept CommonsWare's answer in a minute ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I have multiple IntentServices in my app, can they run in parallel

If you mean that you have multiple subclasses of `IntentService`, they should be able to run in parallel.