# Will two intent services generate two different worker threads or not?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intentservice

I want to do two separate background tasks with `IntentService`, and I want to know if both intent services will generate two separate worker threads or second will wait for first to finish.

Ex.

```
public class IntentServiceOne extends IntentService {
    public IntentServiceOne() {
        super("IntentServiceOne");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
       // code to execute
    }
}

public class IntentServiceSecond extends IntentService {
    public IntentServiceSecond() {
        super("IntentServiceSecond");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
       // code to execute
   }
}
```

Code from activity:

```
Intent intentOne=new Intent(this, IntentServiceOne.class);
startService(intentOne);
Intent intentSecond=new Intent(this, IntentServiceSecond.class);
startService(intentSecond);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just i want to know both intent service will generate two saperate
>   worker thread or second will wait for first to finish.

Both would run independently from each other. Second **will not wait** for first to finish.
Although Each `IntentService` would share same worker instance. So suppose if you call `startService(intentOne);` multiple times your request for this particular service gets `queued`. From [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `IntentService` can run at same time. And they will do their task on separate thread in parallel. You can look at it - [Can multiple Android IntentServices run at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879610/can-multiple-android-intentservices-run-at-the-same-time)